# excessive moisture in crawl space with spray foam insulation

Tags: water

Have new construction in NW florida.  Off grade about 2' with wood frame construction.
Have water running down the driveway and under the house.  It pools up then slow drains in.  I have spray foam insulation.
This doesn't seem like a good idea and builder doesn't want to spend $ for repouring concrete driveway to slope away from house.
Appreciate any advice.
Won't this cause mold eventually and will the insulation seal the house well enough to not be a problem?

Comment: Years later here, how did this turn out?